# Name for this distributed-database data-location optimization algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, mesh, graph-algorithm

Say we have a large graph of databases connected to each other, effectively one giant distributed database.  Any node on the graph can query the whole database by querying its neighbors recursively, which take the results they get from their neighbors and pass the combined result back down the query path.

Also, assume that there's the capability to stop the recursion if a node's own database contains a result that is "good enough", so that the entire network doesn't have to be queried if there's a decent result already nearby.  This makes what I'm about to say relevant.

Wouldn't it make sense to transfer the returned data one step closer to the node that originated the query every time a query is made?  That is, a queried node queries its neighbors and gets X, queries itself and gets Y, passes X+Y back to the node that queried it, stores X in its database, and deletes Y from its database.  Wouldn't this eventually result in the distributed database having a roughly optimal distribution of data among its nodes with respect to the amount of nodes that would be consulted during a query, on average?

Is there a name for this technique?

Comment: This makes kind of sense only if you have a notion of "data locality" - that is, queries originated from a given set of nodes wants a given kind of data (e.g., if your giant database stores HTML pages, queries originated from Italy wants pages in italian). Basically, you are trying to do a form of "distributed caching". What I don't understand is where Y will be stored after all of this. You should pass Y somewhere for storage, not deleting it...

Comment: I don't get why the node would delete its own Y information?

Comment: Y is part of the result passed to the querying node, which stores it.

Comment: @Tobu maybe the global database is huge and frequently queried, so if you didn't delete Y, you'd use too much space on each node's database.  But you're right, if this wasn't the case, then it wouldn't really be necessary to delete it.

Comment: The things your question reminded me of — caching and reinforcement learning — work better when things queried are made more available / given more weight. But that's just analogy.

Comment: @mwhite: so you are replicating the same information all the way from the source database to the requester. Also, databases near the requester will have to store a huge quantity of data.
That's not good... you have to move data, not copy around things many times at every query.
I think an approach based on caching and explicit requests of "move data" between two nodes should be much better.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking:  "Only one step.  If the requester repeats the query many times, then it will eventually be moved all the way."

But actually you're right.  You would need a way to differentiate between your data and your neighbors data in the data that you pass on.  Which is... meh.

And I think you're probably right in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic comes up a lot in grid computing; you want to do a google scholar search for something like [data grid replica placement](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=data%20grid%20replica%20placement).   It works well if there's a lot of time-locality in accesses (if a node wants some data, it'll want it a lot in the near future) and the data is read-mostly.   As yi_H points out, if there's a lot of big modifications of the data, "cache" (replica) coherency becomes a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques like this but you have to be aware that once you "cache" a result you have to update it if when the data changes.. which means either you have to store at the data who caches it, or notify everybody. Implementing something like this requires a lot of coordination which will hurt performance.. not as easy as it sounds. You can also loosen the constraints you database gives you and then be aware in your application that you might get cached results which are out sync (and if neccessary ask for a non-cached version).